How to send a picture via MMS
How can I send an image via SMS/MMS directly from the URL?
I found this code, but it suggests an app to send the MMS instead of directly sending it
val sendIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
sendIntent.setType("image/png"); 


you won't send anything without proper permissions

it already has send sms permission and view storage, does it need some additional ones @snachmsm ?

well, yet another "permission" or setting - only one app can send SMS/MMS and this app is set as preffered in device settings. then you can utilize SmsManager and use it for sendind SMSes. your current way is just an Intent - you "want" to send SMS, dedicated app (according to type/extras) will run and you can't force or even ensure that it disaplys/does what is intended...

btw. when you set your app as default sms/mms sending handler then any other app won't send anything and Intent like in question will be starting your app. Still many apps can show SMS/MMS, so common msg apps will have content, but lose ability to "create new content" (sending msg, which is also stored in local history db)

also some very old DOC when only-one-can-send rule was introduced

@snachmsm so it means the only way to do this would be to have my app be the default SMS/MMS ?

yep, since decade it works like this. only one app can be set as default and the can send, receiving/reading from local msg db is restricted only be permissions and many apps can read msgs
